# Database design for user availability table

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a table in my database which stores information about user availability where there are 21 availability slots: 3 for each day of the week. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_availability(
 id int(11) primary key increments,
 user_id int(11),/*foreign key*/
 day_mon tinyint(1), 
 day_tues tinyint(1), 
 day_wed tinyint(1), 
 day_thurs tinyint(1), 
 day_fri tinyint(1), 
 day_sat tinyint(1), 
 day_sun tinyint(1), 
 eve_mon tinyint(1), 
 eve_tues tinyint(1), 
 eve_wed tinyint(1), 
 eve_thurs tinyint(1), 
 eve_fri tinyint(1), 
 eve_sat tinyint(1), 
 eve_sun tinyint(1), 
 late_mon tinyint(1), 
 late_tues tinyint(1), 
 late_wed tinyint(1), 
 late_thurs tinyint(1), 
 late_fri tinyint(1), 
 late_sat tinyint(1), 
 late_sun tinyint(1)
);
```

This seemed like a good idea at first being super simple to pull the availability for a particular user_id and simply mapping to forms etc. but I've realised it's a poor design with the data in the wrong place effectively forcing relations between tables to be handled in the application rather than the database.

My new design is to have 2 tables:

```
create table user_availabilty(
 id int(11) primary key increments,
 user_id int(11),/*foreign key*/
 time_slot tinyint(2)/*foreign key*/
);

create table time_slots(
 id tinyint(2) primary key,
 name varchar(20)
);
```

Is there anything wrong with this? If my dreams come true one day and I have tens of thousands of users is it going to be an issue having potentially 21 rows in the table per user?

Comment: The "cost" is going to be constant, because the number of these items is contant. So what is the purpose, and what is the expected usage of this information? What will a query look like?

Comment: The intended use is to match contractors with hirers. "What will a query look like?" Good point! I started replying `select distinct user_id from usr_avail where time_slot = 1 and time_slot=2` which I didn't consider won't work in the proposed idea. Hmm it's not ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you could profitably just use bits and bitwise operators for your data.

If your query is going to look like "find me some user that is available in ANY of these time slots" or "find me some user that is available in ALL of these time slots," then you can get that with bitwise-AND.

In MySql, the bitwise operators are the classic C operators: `&`, `|`, and `^`.

You can construct bit masks by enumerating the time slots:

```
mon_day = 0
mon_eve = 1
mon_late = 2
tue_day = 3
tue_eve = 4
tue_late = 5
:
```

Then construct a bitmask using `(1 << X)` where X is any of the enum values. Bitwise-or them all together:

```
#pseudo-code
desired_times = 0

for timeslot in all-timeslots 
begin
    desired_times = desired_times | (1 << timeslot)
end
```

Then your query is a single bit operation:

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
WHERE
    (u.availability & desired_times) = desired_times
```

For an exact match to the times desired (scheduling?), or:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE
    (u.availability & desired_times) != 0
```

For a check to see if the user is available at all.

The benefit here is that it's a quick select, it's compact (only one line in your table definition), it's small (only 32 bits in the row), and it's a pretty direct map to a similar encoding in your "live" data structure, if you have one. And the exact same operations give the exact same results.

Answer (score 0):

My desing is different. Let me share with you;

```
create table user_availabilty(
id int(11) primary increments,
user_id int(11),/*foreign key*/
time_slot_id tinyint(2)/*foreign key*/
);

create table time_slots(
time_slot_id tinyint(2) primary,
user_id , //foreign key
type tinyint(2), // day,eve or late
day_name varchar(10) // days of week
);
```